# Chrome Adds Extra Height to Inline Elements

Tags: html, google-chrome, font-size, css

I'm attempting to add a highlight to a bit of text, but am having issues with the highlight portions height.  The result has been different across browser, but probably the worst is Chrome.  Here is a link to a page illustrating the issue.

http://home.everestkc.net/pardnero/addedheight/

I understand there are ways of getting around this added height, but for other circumstances I've chosen to not to go those routes.  Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could mention what those other ways of getting around it are and why you have rejected them so others don't suggest the same fixes?

Comment: Unless it's something *very* subtle, it looks the same to me in Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari, and Opera.

Comment: Is it a bit subtle, but noticeable enough to create a headache.  You can see that the yellow background of the second line overlaps the other two lines.  In Chrome, the added height of the inline element overlaps the surrounding elements, whereas in FF and some versions of IE, the inline element still has the increased height, but the elements surrounding aren't overlapped.  I would use inline-block, but I need this highlighted text to wrap on to multiple lines, and if I use inline-block the highlight won't be contained to the text, and will instead cover the "block" area.

Comment: The closest method I've used to get rid of this annoying effect is to hide the overflow of the parent element containing the inline element, thereby hiding that added height.  What's extremely strange about this problem is that, although, the line-height and font-size of the parent and inline element are set to X amount, the inline element's height renders to X + ?% (depends on size of text) while the parent's height remains consistent.  After looking at this under the microscope, I'm pretty sure the amount of height added is affected by the size of the font's descenders and ascenders (ex:g f)

Answer (score 0):

Setting `display: inline-block;` on the `<span>` gets the adjacent `<p>` lines to clear it.